# Can I change my character's voice after starting the game?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I created a character in *Dragon Age: Origins* and played with it for a bit. I like how it was built, but forgot to change the voice and I don't like it. Is there any way that I can change it without restarting the character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change the voice in game. If you are on a PC, you can edit the character's save file to use a different voice (this obviously won't work on consoles).

1. Navigate to `<user home>\Documents\BioWare\Dragon Age\Characters\<character name>`
2. Open up `<character name>.xml` in a text editor, such as Notepad++
3. Near the top of the document, find `SoundSet=<some value>`. This is your character's current voice.
4. Change it to a voice of your choice.
5. Save the file

The sound set will be something like `ss_pc_felf_wise`. The format is:

1. Sound set (`ss`)
2. Player character (`pc`)
3. The gender (`m` or `f`) followed by the race (`human`, `elf`, or `dwarf`)
4. The [voice set](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/The_Warden/Voice_Sets) (`wise`, `cocky`, etc.). Note that not all voice sets are available for all genders and races (e.g., `mystical` is not available for dwarves)

You can confirm that the soundset you want exists by examining the data files and finding the file with the same name as the combination you want. For the Steam version, the sound sets exist in `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\Dragon Age Ultimate Edition\packages\core\vo\en-us\vo`. For other versions, navigate to the install directory and go to `\packages\core\vo\en-us\vo`